# AWS Athena MSCK REPAIR TABLE "table_name" Error adding new partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, partition

When trying to refresh the partitions in a AWS Athena/Glue table I am getting this error

> line 1:1: mismatched input 'MSCK'. Expecting: 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE',
> 'CALL', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DEALLOCATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC',
> 'DESCRIBE', 'DROP', 'EXECUTE', 'EXPLAIN', 'GRANT', 'INSERT',
> 'PREPARE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START',
> 'UNLOAD', 'UPDATE', 'USE',

the command I execute is

> MSCK REPAIR TABLE "table_name"

It was working a week ago.
I believe there was an update but I cannot find the new/proper way to add new partitions

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes. I fixed the command.  I first got the error when running from a Lambda and I have confirmed it fails running from AWS Console. From the error it seems the REPAIR option no longer exists

Comment: It worked fine for me, then then I managed to reproduce your error by including the quotes. You need to **remove the quotes from around the table name**.

Comment: that worked, such a poor error message

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. The quotation marks are probably wrong. Try

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the table was attached to a Glue Crawler... So it was just to run the Crawler again!